# Как Найти наибольший из отрицательных элементов. delphi/pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal, алгоритм

Общая постановка. Дана последовательность чисел a1, a2, a3, … . Количество элементов в последовательности заранее неизвестно. Написать программу с запросом продолжения ввода (массив не использовать).
ЗАДАНИЕ: Найти наибольший из отрицательных элементов.
Делал так:
проверял является ли число отрицательным  потом проверял модуль числа с максимальным на данный момент  если больше то перезаписываю imax.

```
 program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
p:Boolean;
c:Char;
a,i,imax:Integer;

begin

  p:=True;
  imax:=0;
  i:=0;

  while p do
      begin
        Write('Vvedite chislo:');
        Readln (a);
        if a<=0 then i:=a;  
        if Abs(i)>=imax then imax:=i;   
        Write('Esho chislo? (y/n)');
        Readln (c);
        if (c='n') or (c='N') then p:=False;
      end;

  Writeln('Max otricatelnoe:', imax);
  readln;
end.
```

Попробовал написать. Но не могу понять алгоритм нахождения наибольшего из отрицательных чисел. В поисках что то тоже ни чего не нашел. Помогите понять алгоритм и что в коде не так.

Comment: В вашем коде ошибка, так как любое число по модулю Abs(i) будет больше любого отрицательного числа imax. Тогда следовало сравнивать оба модуля и с другим знаком: 

> if Abs(i)__<=Abs(imax)__ then imax:=i;

Comment: Исправил. но imax выводит всегда нулем. не могу понять почему так. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Все понял почему не получалось   
Abs(i)>=Abs(imax)поменял знак мне ведь нужно найти наибольшее отрицательное число. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Hakster, определитесь, что значит "наибольшее отрицательное число".

Для меня наибольшее отрицательное число, это то, которое ближе к нулю, а наименьшее отрицательное которое дальше от нуля(из чисел -1,-5,-7,-10 наибольшее -1 и наименьшее -10). Ноль он выдает, поскольку нужно еще найти первое отрицательное и присвоить imax и только потом приводить сравнения  Abs(i)<=Abs(imax).

В вашем же случае ищется самое наименьшее отрицательное, которое дальше от нуля и весь цикл не мудрствуя можно переписать так: if i <= imax then imax:=a; без всяких модулей.

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко (без диалогов, выход - ввод нуля), то может быть так:

```
var 
  n,m : integer;

begin 
  m := -MaxInt;

  repeat readln(n);
    if (n < 0) and (n > m) then m := n
  until n = 0;

  writeln(m)
end.
```